# Why is my filter function not working (PySpark)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So let's say I have an RDD and a list in python. I want to filter the rdd so that for each item in the RDD, it only contains elements which are in the list or an empty list if there are no elements.They look something like this:

rdd = [[], ['F', 'A'], ['A', 'D'], [], []]

listy = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F']

Now if I were to do this with code, I could do something like

```
list1 = ['A', 'D']
set(list1) & set(listy)
```

and the output would be {'A'}. But if I use PySpark's filter function like so:

```
def filter_func(input, valid):
    return set(input).intersection(set(valid)) if input != None else []

filtered = links.filter(lambda x: filter_func(x, listy))
filtered.collect()
```

Then the output is [['F', 'A'], ['A', 'D']]. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can use the map function to get the output I want, but isn't this what the filter function is for?

Comment: Filter in Pyspark will only filter out the elements that satisfy the condition in the RDD. In your case, there are 5 elements in the original RDD, and only 2 elements satisfied the condition, which are ['F', 'A'] and ['A', 'D']. Also note that your filter_func should return True/False value (condition)